# Javascript - Compare user input value to randomly generated value

Tags: javascript, random, switch-statement, compare

I have a function that displays a random word from an array, in a non-repeated way, and a textbox where the user is supposed to type the same generated word.

I tried using a switch statement to validate the user's answer, comparing his input to the randomly generated word, but it is not working.

My question is, is it even possible to compare such things? And if so, how?

This is my code:

```js
// Generate random, non-repeated word
const p = document.getElementById("randomWord");
const origWords = ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo"];
let remainingWords = [];

function randomize() {
  if (remainingWords.length === 0) remainingWords = origWords.slice();
  const {
    length
  } = remainingWords;
  const [quote] = remainingWords.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * length), 1);
  p.textContent = quote;
}
randomize();

// Validate answer
function submit001() {
  var answers = document.getElementById("input001").value.toLowerCase();
  switch (answers, remainingWords) {
    case "":
      text = "Please write something.";
      break;
    case answers == remainingWords:
      text = "Correct.";
      randomize();
      break;
    default:
      text = "Wrong.";
  }
  document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input001" autofocus maxlength="7" spellcheck="false" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) submit001();">
<p id="randomWord"></p>
<p id="comment"></p>
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible to do. However, you need to revise your `switch` syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` statement is probably a more appropriate solution to the problem. Try this:

```js
// Generate random, non-repeated word
const p = document.getElementById("randomWord");
const origWords = ["alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo"];
let remainingWords = [];

function randomize() {
  if (remainingWords.length === 0) remainingWords = origWords.slice();
  const length = remainingWords;
  const [quote] = remainingWords.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * length), 1);
  p.textContent = quote;
}
randomize();

// Validate answer
function submit001() {
  var answers = document.getElementById("input001").value.toLowerCase();
  if (answers == "") {
    text = "Please write something.";
  } else if (answers == p.textContent) {
    text = "Correct.";
    randomize();
  } else {
    text = "Wrong.";
  }
  document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = text
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input001" autofocus maxlength="7" spellcheck="false" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) submit001();">
<p id="randomWord"></p>
<p id="comment"></p>
```